# Upgraded Android SDK, now crashes Android Studio IDE when running app

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, fatal-error

I have just upgraded the Android SDK from 19 to 22. I can build the app just fine, but when I run it asks me to choose what device to run on and then Android Studio terminates.

I cannot even test my app as it simply shuts down Android Studio every time.

Comment: Version of Android Studio?

Comment: Where is the error? The stacktrace?

Comment: I updated to a later version of gradle, I was on 1.0.0, set now to 1.1.0, everything works fine